# Why Dependency Injenct only works in Resource class in jersey

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, jersey-2.0

I am trying to use test database for my application. I am using MyBatis. 
I have 2 environments configured in MyBatis configuration file. I have set property like so in my ResourceConfig subclass.

```
property("Env","development");
```

I am able to get this value i,e **development** in my Resource like fallows

```
@Context Application app;// this is instance variable

System.out.println(app.getProperties().get("Env"));// this statement in resource method
```

I have 3 layers Controller(i,e Resource class), Action Layer and DAO and DMO mapper layer.

But the above 2 statements which are working in resource class is not working in DAO class. I am getting a NullPointerException at `System.out.println` Line

Now I have to get the environment in Resource and pass it to further layers. Is there a better way to do this.

All I want is to choose test database for testing and development database for development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely because you are just trying to instantiate the DAO youself

```
@Path("boogers")
class Resource {
   Dao dao = new Dao()
}
```

That's not going to work. The `Dao` needs to go through Jersey's injection system. The resource works because it goes through the injection system. If you want to do the same for your `Dao`, then you need to inject it and let it go through the DI system. That way the system will inject it with required dependencies before injecting it into the resource

```
@Path("boogers")
class Resource {
   @Inject
   Dao dao;
}
```

Here, you don't instantiate it, You let the DI system create it and inject it. To make it work, you need to make the `Dao` injectable.

```
class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppConfig() {
        register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bindAsContract(Dao.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here you're binding the `Dao` class to the injection system, so that whenever it sees `@Inject Dao`, it will be able to grab/create it and inject it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your study and knowledge . This helped me a  understanding DI more . The article on DI using Jersey's HK2 framework is also very informative and helpful thanks